# Significance of $N(T^t)=R(T)^0$.

Tags: dual-spaces, transpose

I know that if $T:V\to W$ is a linear transformation where $V,W$ are finite dimensional.Then we have $Ker(T^t)=Im(T)^0$.But how to geometrically interpret this thing.What does it mean and why this has to be true?Can someone give me a clue?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that $0$ in the exponent.

Comment: @GerryMyerson most likely the annihilator of the range (or image) of $T.$

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes,annihilator

Comment: If $T$ were a $n \times m$ real matrix, we would have $Tx \cdot y = x \cdot T^t y,  \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R^m, y \in \mathbb R^n$. Here, $\cdot$ is the usual dot product. Now, if you take $y \in \ker T^t$, you see that $y \in \text{Im} (T)^0$ and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$T = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & ... & z_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & ... & z_2\\
. & . &... & .\\
a_n & b_n & ... & z_n
\end{pmatrix}$$

The range $R(T) = span \left\{  
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
. \\
a_n 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
. \\
b_n 
\end{pmatrix}
...
\begin{pmatrix}
z_1 \\
z_2 \\
. \\
z_n 
\end{pmatrix}
 \right\}$.

A selection of linearly independent column vectors can form a basis for the range of $T$.

The annihilator $R(T)^0 = \{s : s \in W , r \in R(T), sr = 0\}$

The annihilator is the set of vectors $s$ that take every vector $r$ in the range to zero.

In this case $sr$ is a dot product.

$s.a = 0$, $s.b = 0$,...,$s.z = 0$.

$s$ are normal to the column vectors in $T$.

$$T^t = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & ... & a_n \\
b_1 & b_2 & ... & b_n\\
. & . &... & .\\
z_1 & z_2 & ... & z_n
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$N(T^t) = \{w: T^tw = 0, w \in W\}$$

$T^tw = 0$ solves for $w.a = 0$, $w.b = 0$ ... $w.z = 0$.

$w$ are normal to the row vectors in $T^t$.

So the spans of $s$ and $w$ are identical, they solve the same equations.

$$N(T^t) = R(T)^0$$

Generalizing. The annihilators of $R(T)$ are normal to the basis of $R(T)$.
The null space vectors of $T^t$ are normal to the same vectors.